# Multiply login forms Spring Security GWT

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, spring-security

I want to make 2 different login forms (jsp) for my application. but just 2 different forms with the same authentication managers. Is this even possible? I just read that you could only use 1 auth manager but nobody talked about different forms. 
Has anybody tried it?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Which approach do you use for Spring Security + GWT pair? A JSP page with login form and then redirect to GWT host page in a case of success?

Comment: ok, but they differ between 2 different access  roles, i only have on. Is it also possible how to say spring when to use what. or is the pattern enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many login forms as you want. Just place it on every JSP page you want:

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
    User:
    <input type='text' name='j_username' />
    Password:
    <input type='password' name='j_password' />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

It does not metter how many login forms do you have. They all will be submitted to the same `j_spring_security_check` URL and so they all will be processed by the same spring security filter. The same auhentication manager will be used.

You can have multiple authentication managers.